# Finding or configuring Solr home directory

Tags: solr

I'm following this tutorial on setting up django-haystack and solr: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

I hit a stumbling block here:

> If you’re using the Solr backend, you have an extra step. Solr’s
> configuration is XML-based, so you’ll need to manually regenerate the
> schema. You should run ./manage.py build_solr_schema first, **drop the
> XML output in your Solr’s schema.xml file** and restart your Solr
> server.

Where is my schema.xml file located? It says it should in the Solr home directory and the .conf folder. But where is the Solr home directory, and/or how do I configure its location?

Comment: May I know if the answer was helpful? If so, you might want to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

The solr home is the place where you can find your [`schema.xml`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) and [`solrconfig.xml`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml), as well as some other files depending on the text analysis you're using (dictionaries for stemming, stopwords etc.), and where your index gets created by default.

There are a couple of ways to configure the solr home, since it is located outside of the servlet container:

- solr.solr.home java system property (most used one)
- java:comp/env/solr/home for JNDI lookup

You can either check your servlet container configuration or go to the Solr admin page `http://host:port/solr/admin`, which prints out the actual solr home location together with other information about the solr instance running.

Comment: I have the same problem I dont know where to put my schema.xml, I tried http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/admin (as i defined it in my HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL) but it gives me a 404

Comment: In recent versions of tomcat-solr, solrconfig.xml, schema.xml, and (optionally) solr.xml can be found in the "conf" dir of solr.home. For example, in /usr/share/solr/conf (which is usually a symbolic link to /etc/solr/conf).

Answer (score 1):

First check whether your Solr instance is working.
Got to -> http://localhost:8983/solr

If you can see a Solr web panel you have a live Solr instance.
Now go to **Java Properties**
[image: Solr Java Properties Link]

Here you will see the the variables. This is where you can find the home DIRs
[image]

Note schema is now managed. If you want to override this you will have to hack it a bit. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43713143/1998725)